# Let $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, and define $A \cdot B := \{a \cdot b \; | \; a \in A, b \in B\}$.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

If $A$ and $B\;$ are open ($\mathbb{R}$ with standard topology), is it also true that $A \cdot B\;$ must be open?

And what if both are closed; is it also true that $A \cdot B\;$ must be closed?

I was only able to tell that if both are compact, then $A \cdot B\;$ must be compact. My reasoning is as follows: let $f : A \times B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f(x, y) = xy$. The cartesian product of compact sets is compact, so $A \times B\;$ is compact; and since $f$ is continuous and the image of compact sets under continuous functions is compact, $f(A \times B) = A \cdot B \;$ is compact. I think the proof is correct, but any help in proving it only with the definition of compactness (and maybe Heine-Borel) would be very welcome.

Comment: Try to find a counterexample for the "closed" assertion. As you noted, such counterexample must have sets $A,B$ that are closed and unbounded.  Hint: let one of the sets be $A=\mathbb Z$.  Then arrange that the point $1/2$ is in the closure of $A\cdot B$ but not in $A \cdot B$.  Of course you have to find a set $B$ to make this work.

Comment: Hint: Take a point $x \in A \cdot B$, then $x=a b $ for some $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. As $A$ is open, exists a open ball $C$ centered in $a$ and contained in $A$. Then try to proove that $C \cdot b \subset B$ is a open ball centerder in $a b $.